# how to add ~/.vimrc file to ~/.ideavimrc

Tags: vim, webstorm, ideavim

How can I add `~/.vimrc` to `~/.ideavimrc`? I've used the command `source ~/.vimrc` in 
`~/.ideavimrc` file.

**~/.vimrc file**

```
command! Wq :wq
```

**~/.ideavimrc file**

```
source ~/.vimrc
```

When I type my own command  `Wq` in webstorm I get something like this: Unexpected character ':' in range |:wq. How can I achieve this? Any help will highly appreciated.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue in IdeaVim. Try to replace `command! Wq :wq` with `command! Wq wq`.

I've filed a ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-2005

Comment: Thanks for creating ticket. Your solution worked for Wq when I removed `:` from file but there is two other commands I've which are Fcomments and Ccomments; They supposed to open file on file. I mean it will put comments to above the code when I type Fcomments for this I've used `:r` command on file such as `command! Fcomment :r fileDirectory`

Comment: removing `:` before r wasn't the solution.